# How to solve memory consumption in windows phonw 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have been working on a WP8 app, it's image gallery app,,Here I have been using pivot control &list box to collect Camera Roll images(dynamically) from the device  and swipe one by one,it is working fine But I found app's memory consumption is raising and How to resolve this?

I am trying to figure out how to code a program where I have an list of images, where only one image is shown at a time, but the adjacent images are preloaded but not visible. After each flick, the now current image animates itself over to the visible area, and the adjacent images are updated, but not visible until the next flick in either direction. I only want to have 3 'boxes'(cycle),consisting of the image to the left, current image on screen, and the image to the right. If revolving to the right, the current image becomes the left image, the image to the right becomes the current image, and the next image is preloaded but not visible.

Example:

First image you see is when the app is loaded. It's essentially the first image in the List box .Call it (Image 1).

You cannot flick to the left, as no image is there. But the image to the right of it (not visible yet) is already preloaded and ready to slide when the flick is registered. (image 2)

So if we flick to the right, Image 1 is to the left of the now visible and centered Image 2. Image 3 is now to the right, not visible but preloaded. Image 1 is now to the left, not visible but preloaded.

**I only want to have 2 things preloaded now, so you can imagine 3 slots. One slot is the left picture. One slot is the current view, and one slot on the right.

The idea is to be able to have a carousel of images, but only preloading the images to the left and right of the current view.

Comment: My Question is how to create  imagine 3 slots out of list of images. One slot is the left picture. One slot is the current view, and one slot on the right.For more clarification see above description.

Comment: System display Out of memory exception when 9 images load.Any one can Provide simple code for above issue..

Comment: Still i am working for same issue.System display Out of memory exception when 9 image load.

Comment: First image you see is when the app is loaded. It's essentially the first image in the List box .Call it (Image 1).

You cannot flick to the left, as no image is there. But the image to the right of it (not visible yet) is already preloaded and ready to slide when the flick is registered. (image 2)

So if we flick to the right, Image 1 is to the left of the now visible and centered Image 2. Image 3 is now to the right, not visible but preloaded. Image 1 is now to the left, not visible but preloaded.How to solve these problem ?

Comment: I have try to solve  but still it pending.So if we flick to the right, Image 1 is to the left of the now visible and centered Image 2. Image 3 is now to the right, not visible but preloaded. Image 1 is now to the left, not visible but preloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Lens example on MSDN here : http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Basic-Lens-sample-359fda1b it has a MediaViewer class that handles images as a image carousel and does virtualization.

Comment: My Question is how to create imagine 3 slots out of list of images. One slot is the left picture. One slot is the current view, and one slot on the right.For more clarification see above description.

Comment: Ha, you mean visually? There is something like that available here: http://sigurdsnorteland.wordpress.com/2010/09/19/wp7-samples-upgraded-to-rtm/ > cover control

Comment: No, It's like image gallery app,,Here I have been using pivot control &list box to collect Camera Roll images(dynamically) from the device and swipe one by one like media library.

Comment: it is working fine But I found app's memory consumption is raising because all images store list box one by one and display it.i.s. I have use list box to collect all camera roll images and display it but i have need  3 images cycle to continue 1)current,2)preview,3)nextImage..these 3 state must change value or reflect another image

Comment: no more images store in memory only 3 images store in memory. For more reference see above description of question,Provide simple code for above issue.

Comment: System display Out of memory exception when 9 image load.

Comment: I don't get it... when I suggested the MediaViewer class, you stated that was not what you were looking for. But your updated description in the question suggests it is! The MediaViewer class will allow you to show one image and go through others whith guestures and does virtualization to lower memory usage.

Comment: The MediaViewer class will allow you to show one image and go through others whith gestures.But does't show "first","next" "previous" swipe image logic ,where  my question was i  created list box to collect all camera  roll images and show one by one it consumes lots of memory,i.s.after 9 image display system through "OutOfMemory Exception",

Comment: Then i think the solution was in list box store only 3 images first,next&previous.if user swipe first image right to left then previous image must delete&first image store previous image space also next image come first image position and next image position can retrieve image from  camera roll next image etc.cycle will continue left and right swipe image...These logic i was try to implement,but still not implement..

Answer (score 0):

You have to either de-allocate the memory consumed by outgoing image or re-use it to load the incoming image.

Can you be a little more clear exactly what you have done and where you are facing a difficulty?

Comment: Hi,I was created listbox to store all camera roll images and listbox include 100+ images,also use pivot app for swipe one by one but i have face memory problem,i have looking only  3 images "First,Next,Last" images add at a time if user swipe first image then previous image delete that time add next images in these cycle etc way only 3 images store in memory &these images change cycle wise for more clarification see question description,if any one solve these problem then provide simple code for these problem.

Comment: I have done give camera roll images and swipe one by one like media library only i have need 3 image cycle slot, FIRST,NEXT,PREVIOUS,IF i swipe  first image then next image come first image position,also next image position pickup list box new image (Serially) Also delete First image etc.cycle wise image add .

Comment: How do I start a bounty? for above question.

Comment: are you storing bitmapimages of all camera roll images in your list? or just the path to the image